# sbt test is picking up wrong resource folder path

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a test that does

```
val url = getClass.getResource("/test.jpg")
val path = url.getPath
```

Using sbt test, the path is wrongly identified as
/Users/Me/IdeaProjects/myProject/target/scala-2.11/myProject_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/test.jpg

However in Intellij, the path is correct
/Users/Me/IdeaProjects/myProject/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/test.jpg

How can i get sbt to pick up the correct resource path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely reason is that you have `exportJars := true` in your SBT build:

> By default, a project exports a directory containing its resources and compiled class files. Set exportJars to true to export the packaged jar instead. For example,
>
> ```
> exportJars := true
> ```
>
> The jar will be used by run, test, console, and other tasks that use the full classpath

(http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Package.html). If you want to change it specifically for tests, use `exportJars in Test := false`.